# Issue with Spring and MongoDB Atlas connection: Network is unreachable

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I'm creating a simple web app for class that will use a MongoDB Atlas database, but I can't make any network connection.  I have a user account set up, have 0.0.0.0/0 whitelisted, and believe I have the code setup correctly for a connection.  When I try running to test the app, I get `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable` all over the place.  With the console log below, does anyone see an obvious error?  I have tried the ports to make sure they are open and haven't found an error, not sure why the connection totally fails.

application.properties:

```
# MongoDB Atlas - Connection
spring.data.mongodb.database=bookclub
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://bookclub_user:<pwd>@cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bookclub</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookclub</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bookclub</name>
    <description>CIS 530 Bookclub Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Form validation fields -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf template engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MongoDB Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

NEW console output:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

2021-10-04 04:52:24.130  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] com.bookclub.BookclubApplication         : Starting BookclubApplication using Java 16.0.2 on C02YPFQ9LVCG with PID 36899 (/Users/abecthold/Courses/cis-530/bookclub/target/classes started by abecthold in /Users/abecthold/Courses/cis-530/bookclub)
2021-10-04 04:52:24.132  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] com.bookclub.BookclubApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-04 04:52:24.169  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-10-04 04:52:24.169  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-10-04 04:52:24.574  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-10-04 04:52:24.582  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-10-04 04:52:24.914  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-10-04 04:52:24.921  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-10-04 04:52:24.921  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-10-04 04:52:24.968  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-10-04 04:52:24.968  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 798 ms
2021-10-04 04:52:25.059  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-10-04 04:52:25.127  INFO 36899 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1517) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2021-10-04 04:52:25.185  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-10-04 04:52:25.394  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2021-10-04 04:52:25.485  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-10-04 04:52:25.493  INFO 36899 --- [  restartedMain] com.bookclub.BookclubApplication         : Started BookclubApplication in 1.608 seconds (JVM running for 2.09)
2021-10-04 04:52:35.129  INFO 36899 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:886) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

New errors on web view when trying to connect through the app:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}}]
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}}
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net}}]
```

Comment: Could you please provide your application.properties file? How do you manage the connection to the database?

Comment: Just edited, they should show now

Comment: Does your cluster allow public access? It seems you cant reach it from your network.  Verify that it is public first

Comment: @SusanMustafa How do I allow public access to the cluster?  I thought that is what whitelisting 0.0.0.0/0 did.

Comment: Can you ping cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net ?   Using +srv is equivalent to TLS.  is 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports?  Can you try without +srv, just mongodb and see if it connects?

Comment: @SusanMustafa Looks like removing +srv from my application.properties has helped, but I'm now getting some fun new errors.  At least the application will run now!  I'll post the new console output in an edit on the main post, I'm getting "MongoSocketException" and "UnknownHostException" now.  I am not able to ping cluster0.ne3yt.mongodb.net, can't resolve hostname

Comment: You are going through a VPN of some sort aren't you? @rbecthold

Comment: That could be part of the issue now, I am at work currently.  I will try once I get home later and am on my home network.  Could that be the cause of these new errors? @SusanMustafa

Comment: Are you able to connect from any tools like `mongo` shell or Compass?

Comment: @prasad_ I can connect with mongosh, looks like there's something up with my implementation then?

Comment: I also tracked down an error to my list() function that calls mongoTemplate.findAll(), could that be because I don't have any sample data in the database yet?

Comment: Any update on this? I ran into a similar issue. I am able to connect to mongodb via compass but not working in springboot. TIA.